# Does Nightingale armor scale as you level light armor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am looking at a build centered around light armor, the lord stone, mara's blessing and breton resistences. One of the armors I would like to use is the nightingale one. From what I read it is leveled, what I would like to know is does it scale with your level or is it locked to the level you get it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Levelled rewards scale with your character level (i.e., the level you are when you first receive it) rather than scaling with a skill.

The [Nightingale Armor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveled_Items#Nightingale_Armor) does have 3 levelled variants, so if you're a higher level when you receive it, you'll get the stronger version. Once you get it, however, it will not change, even as you grow in level.

Armor in general scales with your Light Armor skill, but this only increases the Armor Rating, never the enchantment (which is where the levelled rewards differ).

Comment: So if I am reading you correct the only downside to getting the armor early is the enchantment level?

Comment: @DeanMc in this case, yes.

Comment: Do you know what the level breaks are for the variants?  I've not been able to figure that one out.

Comment: @Cloudancer I do not, sadly. :(

Answer (score 2):

[Yes.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveled_Items#Nightingale_Armor) On hitting levels 19 and 32, the armor provides 10 more stamina points. Cold resistance also improves together with stamina:

```
  Level         Stamina    Frost res.
---------------------------------------
   1-18              20           15%
  19-31              30           30%
  32-max             40           50%
```

Comment: We frown on answers that are nothing but links. Please consider including a summary in your own words of the important data behind your link next time, as I've done